# How to print a reversed ascii tree?

Tags: python, tree

[asciitree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asciitree) draws ASCII trees as follows:

```
root
  +--sub1
  +--sub2
  |  +--sub2sub1
  +--sub3
     +--sub3sub1
     |  +--sub3sub1sub1
     +--sub3sub2
```

Any hint how to print the 'reversed' tree with python? Here an example:

```
       sub3sub2--+
sub3sub1sub1--+  |
       sub3sub1--+
              sub3--+
       sub2sub1--+  |
              sub2--+
              sub1--+
                 root
```

[asciitree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asciitree) uses following node-structure:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, children):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Yes, I've started to adapt the code of [asciitree._draw_tree](https://github.com/mbr/asciitree/blob/master/asciitree.py#L16) but I search for an algorithm that helps calculating the rtl spacing of the nodes. I believe having seen this before in some pydocs(?) documentation where the class hierarchy is printed that way. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just invert the output of `asciitree`:

```
lines = output.splitlines()[::-1]
width = max(len(l) for l in lines)

reversed = []
for line in lines:
    tree, dashes, label = line.rpartition('--')
    tree = (tree + dashes)[::-1]
    line = '{1:>{0}}{2}'.format(width - len(tree), label, tree).rstrip()
    reversed.append(line)

print '\n'.join(reversed)
```

Demo:

```
>>> output = '''\
... root
...   +--sub1
...   +--sub2
...   |  +--sub2sub1
...   +--sub3
...      +--sub3sub1
...      |  +--sub3sub1sub1
...      +--sub3sub2
... '''
>>> lines = output.splitlines()[::-1]
>>> width = max(len(l) for l in lines)
>>> reversed = []
>>> for line in lines:
...     tree, dashes, label = line.rpartition('--')
...     tree = (tree + dashes)[::-1]
...     line = '{1:>{0}}{2}'.format(width - len(tree), label, tree).rstrip()
...     reversed.append(line)
... 
>>> print '\n'.join(reversed)
       sub3sub2--+
sub3sub1sub1--+  |
       sub3sub1--+
              sub3--+
       sub2sub1--+  |
              sub2--+
              sub1--+
                   root
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!